# putting a row array into an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, csv

I have the following code:

```
 try {
     CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
     parserSettings.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true);
     RowListProcessor rowProcessor = new RowListProcessor();
     parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
     parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
     CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

     parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\GeoIPCountryWhois.csv"));

  String[] headers = rowProcessor.getHeaders();
List<String[]> rows = rowProcessor.getRows();
for (int index = 0;index< rows.size();index++){
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rows.get(index)));
}

 } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(MyThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

This creates a row of array each time
like below

```
[1.0.1.0, 1.0.3.255, 16777472, 16778239, CN, China]
[1.0.4.0, 1.0.7.255, 16778240, 16779263, AU, Australia]
[1.0.8.0, 1.0.15.255, 16779264, 16781311, CN, China]
```

However i want to put my data into one single array, how can i do this?

Comment: Do you want all rows in one array?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "all classes in one array"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean an array of arrays?

```
List<String[]> rows = rowProcessor.getRows();
String[][] rowsArray = rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()][]); //this contains an array of all your rows
```

To Verify:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowsArray[i]));
}
```

This would give the same output as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this..

```
List<String[]> rows = rowProcessor.getRows();

List<String> oneList = rows.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
String[] oneArray = oneList.toArray(new String[0]);
```